# sql question .. how can i dynamically add columns to a sql query result set?

Tags: sql, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I am writing a report to return details about an object ('files') in my database. My application lets users create their own flags for use against file objects. Flags basically consist of a name, then flag instances store a bit value to indicate whether it is set for the parent file object.

I want to write a query that returns one row per file in the database, where the first few columns in the result set contain the file details (id, name, size etc) and the remaining columns are the flag names, with bit values returned to indicate whether the flag is set for the given file row.

Does that make sense? How do i go about writing the query?

Thanks for any help.

Edit: Clarification..

As part of this query, I need to run a sub query that returns the flags that have been created by the user (I do not know these at design time), then incorporate a check for each flag value in the main query to return details about the files.

Simplified schema as follows:

- File {Id, Name}
- Flag {Id, Name}
- FileFlags {FileId, FlagId} - a row in this table indicates that the flag is set for the file

I need the query to return a result set with columns something like this:

**FileId**     **FileName**     **Flag1Name**     **Flag2Name**  ....   **FlagNName**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by looking at the [Pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) function available in SQL Server 2005+. With that and some string concatenation you should be able to assemble a query for any number of columns

Based on your comment your select would look something like this:

```
        SELECT <non-pivoted column>,

            [first pivoted column] AS <column name>,

            [second pivoted column] AS <column name>, ...
    From Table 
    PIVOT (
...
FOR 
...
)
```

Comment: i think this will get close to what i need, though i only need to pivot part of the result set.. is that possible?

Comment: thanks for the response jeremy. i now understand the pivot function and it is the right approach. the problem i have is that i dont know the pivoted columns when im writing the query - i need to insert them as part of the query itself, rather than hardcode them. does that make sense? all the pivot examples i can find are hardcoding the pivoted column names :(

Comment: ok, ive found some tutorials on dynamically generating columns in a pivot statement. it looks pretty horrible, but im on the right path. thanks jeremy

Comment: Yes, 'horrible' is how I would describe it.  But writing the actual query dynamically is pretty much the only way MS SQL Server can do this...

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a stored procedure with the required logic - querying user-specific flags, etc - and on that basis dynamically build a query string with the variables you need?

You can then use `EXECUTE` to return the dynamic query set to the user. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like perhaps you need a crosstab query, where you want to turn rows into columns.  Are the flags stored in a separate table as a one to many relationship to the parent table?

Comment: I think you want to do a join perhaps, not a subquery, then use a crosstab report process to convert rows to columns.

The issue may be it soudns as if every row you want back could have different columns due to each having different flags so not sure how you could return them as unique columns across all rows.

Comment: youre right about the potential issue of different columns, but im quite happy to return all flags as columns and then just indicate whether they are set or not, if that makes sense... my sql skills arent up to much :o

Answer (score -1):

I think you want is an alias. Here is an example from http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-Aliases.asp

```
SELECT Employee, SUM(Hours) AS SumHoursPerEmployee
FROM EmployeeHours
GROUP BY Employee
```

I would really have to see your schema to help further.

**Edit**
Maybe you need nested `SELECT`s.
http://sqlzoo.net/1a.htm

Comment: no sorry, that isn't what im after. i need a dynamic query where the result of a sub query forms part of the main query. i dont see what aliases have got to do with it...